# Overiding a prototype method

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript base function like this;

```
roomBase = function () {
  this.go = function(){
    alert(1);
  }
}
```

I have a room object like this;

```
myRoom = function(){
  this.go = function(){
    alert(456);
  }
}
myRoom.prototype = new roomBase();
theRoom = new myRoom();
```

When I call `theRoom.go()` I am getting an alert from the `prototype`.  What I want is the alert from the `myRoom` function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me. (it alerts `456`)

Are you sure everything is running correctly?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9hWAr/

Code for Demo:

```
var roomBase = function () {
  this.go = function(){
    alert(1);
  }
}

var myRoom = function(){
  this.go = function(){
    alert(456);
  }
}
myRoom.prototype = new roomBase();
var theRoom = new myRoom();

theRoom.go()
```

Comment: I was until I saw your jsfiddle.  let me look closer again.  thanks

Comment: No problem @griegs you might have an error somewhere else in your code that is not in your OP

Comment: +1 You are absolutely right. I think I may now be calling the wrong object which raises even more questions.

Comment: @griegs Thanks, well then :-) only thing to do is to make a new question with fuller code.

Comment: No that's fine, I just need to ensure I am calling what I'm expecting to call and maybe revisit my object hierarchy.

Comment: Actually, I've found the issue but do you know how to call the prototypes go method?

Comment: No problem @griegs ^_^